# Load Testing a Website with a Certificate

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, load-testing

My website requires that the user choose a certificate before gaining access.

I'd like to use `ab`, `Siege`, or `JMeter` to test out the performance of my website since I've at least heard of them.

However, how is it possible to include the certificate so that I can authenticate, and thus actually hit Tomcat for load testing?